# Change the .Text property of TextBoxes in an array of TextBox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have an array of textboxes. Lets say this one:

```
Dim BreakFast1() As TextBox = {txtMBreak1, txtTBreak1, txtWBreak1, txtThBreak1, txtFBreak1, txtSBreak1, txtSunBreak1}
```

What i want to do is set the .Text property for each of the textboxes of the array.I have tried this:

```
For i As Integer=0 to 6
  BreakFast1(i).Text= "Smt"
Next
```

With no success. What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: That should work (although I would recommend a `For Each` loop instead).  What about it doesn't work?  Does it throw an exception?  Does it fail to compile?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Throws a NullReferenceException. I should check if the object is null or use the "New" keyword to create an object instance.. Why is For Each better?

Comment: I think all of them. I tried setting the i value manually (ex BreakFast1(2).Text="blah blah") but still throws the exception

Comment: Are the variables you used to fill the array also null?  For instance, if you put a break point on the `Dim BreakFast1()...` line, and you hover over `txtMBreak1`, does it say it's null, or does it say if references a TextBox object?  What about all the other ones?

Comment: Yeap it says nothing. Shall i declare them inside the array as new textbox etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, but that assumes the text boxes you are adding to the array actually reference instantiated `TextBox` objects.  If those are null, it obviously won't work.  To fix that, you have several options:

- Move the `Dim BreakFast1()...` line down below where those text box object get instantiated.
- Set the text box variables to new instances before that line.
- Or, forgo all those text box variables and just instantiate them directly into the array.

For instance:

```
Dim BreakFast1() As TextBox = {New TextBox(), New TextBox(), New TextBox(), New TextBox(), New TextBox(), New TextBox(), New TextBox()}
```

When you loop through them, I would recommend using a `For Each` loop, instead (unless there's some other reason why you need to know the index inside the loop):

```
For Each i As TextBox In BreakFast1
    i.Text = "Smt"
Next
```